# Awk, compare 2 files and write out incomparables

Tags: unix, awk

I usually use

```
awk BEGIN {FS=" "} NR==FNR{arry[$1]=$0; next} $1 in array && $0=arr[$1] FS in fields infile1 infile2 > outfile
```

to extract common fields in 2 files based on field of interest. But this time I need incomparables. I have 2 files with equal lines but 200 lines in the second file do not have the same coding as in `file1`.

I tried to :

```
paste f1 f2 | sort -n -k1,2
```

by both fields hoping to get `$1==$2` and take unequal fields but I don't get `$1==$2` even when there should be.

How can I do this?

Comment: if you dont have to do it with awk, just do `comm -3 file1 file2`

Comment: @Marcin I didn't have to use awk. This works just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seems to compare by the first field and since I don't know what your data files look like, I am going to blindly attempt at this:

```
$ cat data1.txt
dana 100
john 101
fiona 102

$ cat data2.txt
dana 100
john 501
fiona 102

$ cat data[12].txt|sort|uniq -u
john 101
john 501
```

The above solution will prints out lines that are not the same, based on the first field. Since I don't fully understand your data file, I am going ask this question. Does the following solve your problem?

```
diff data1.txt data2.txt
```